# Visual Studio 2010 Crystal Reports HyperLink

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I am using the embedded Crystal Reports tool in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.  How do you create a hyperlink?  It will allow me to make an entire section (select section and click object properties) of text a hyperlink, but what if I want to just make one or two words of a text block a hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Right click on your object -> Format Object -> Hyperlink tab

[image]

You cannot make a hyperlink of one or two words. Crystal Report only allows you to make hyperlink on objects.